# Handle the same nullable Entity relation at both SQL and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I would like to project an entity, and a non-nullable property of a 1 - 0..1 related entity, into a new result. It's a common need, similar to [How to select non nullables from nullable relation in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330892/how-to-select-non-nullables-from-nullable-relation-in-entity-framework)

No problem, you say, right? In my case, I simply coalesce the value with a non-nullable fallback.

```
appointment => new ClientAppointmentViewModel
{
    Id = appointment.Id,
    Phone = appointment.Phone.Normalized ?? appointment.Client.Phone.Normalized,
```

An appointment may not have a one-time `Phone` number associated with it, so instead we'll call the client's profile phone number. Yay!

However, the question is, **can I write this as shared code to run against SQL data AND in-memory Entities?**

This executes fine *as a store expression*. When I retrieve a list of `ClientAppointmentViewModel` directly from the database, all is well. The entire SQL query relationship generated from `appointment.Phone.Normalized` is interpreted as one nullable value, and the coalesce works fine.

However, I also use it on a single in-memory entity instance. Suppose I've inserted an appointment and am returning the single resulting `ClientAppointmentViewModel` for confirmation in my UI. In this case, my appointment is already in-memory, so the transformation runs as C# and returns a null reference error: `appointment.Phone` is sometimes null.

I could go the other way, and extend my Entity with a property (e.g. `FallbackPhone`) that executes conditional logic. This will run fine on an in-memory instance, but will fail to translate to a store expression. It won't run at all against SQL.

How can I write this logic once, to represent both cases?

Comment: Is this for running automated tests on your linq code?

Comment: No, it's to transform repository data models into view models on a RESTful API. Does that make sense?

Comment: What happens if you use a tertiary expression? `Phone = appointment.Phone != null && appointment.Phone.Normalized != null ?  appointment.Phone.Normalized : appointment.Client.Phone.Normalized`

Comment: Yes, that worked Colin. Also `(appointment.Phone ?? appointment.Client.Phone).Normalized`